# Building/Compiling Opus (libopus) In Emscripten with Optimization

Tags: emscripten, webassembly, opus

Is it possible to build/compile Opus/libopus with optimization using Emscripten?I'm unsure if this is a current limitation of Emscripten and WebAssembly in general or if options exist to ensure the decoder is optimized in WebAssembly (wasm).

---

I receive the following warning below for `opus_decoder`:

```
  CC       src/opus_decoder.lo
src/opus_decoder.c:37:10: warning: You appear to be compiling without optimization, if so
opus will be very slow. [-W#pragma-messages]
```

This warning is not produced when compiling Opus normally without the Emscripten wrappers:

```
$ ./configure --disable-intrinsics --disable-rtcd
$ make
```

The warning is introduced when wrapping:

```
$ emconfigure ./configure --disable-intrinsics --disable-rtcd
$ emmake make
```

Using:

- emcc 1.37.35
- Opus v1.3-beta - also tested today's master ([`d01199b`](https://github.com/xiph/opus/tree/d01199be4cf3257478bd04ed028e3c589d306215))

Comment: You can pass in `CFLAGS` to `make` or `configure` like `$ emconfigure ./configure --disable-intrinsics --disable-rtcd CFLAGS='-O2'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass in `CFLAGS` into the configure step like this:

```
emconfigure ./configure --disable-intrinsics --disable-rtcd CFLAGS='-O2'
```

This will enable optimizations and hide the message.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're running it in emscripten, so it isn't going to be fast anyway ...  :)

The issue is that if you fake being gcc but aren't actually an x86 target, you get hit with this message.

You can either ignore the message (the optimizations appear to only be for x86) or define OPUS_WILL_BE_SLOW (-DOPUS_WILL_BE_SLOW) to make it go away.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested webassembly yet, but I've compiled in the past using emscripten to create code to be used with asm.js and I've used this options for emcc

```
EMCC_OPTS=-O3 --memory-init-file 0 -s BUILD_AS_WORKER=1 -s NO_EXIT_RUNTIME=1 -s NO_FILESYSTEM=1 -s EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS="['_malloc']" -s EXPORTED_RUNTIME_METHODS="['setValue', 'getValue']"
```

Comment: @RyanSppets comment above solved the issue by introducing the optimization flag